# How long does it take for Google Analytics Goals to start show some data?

Tags: google-analytics

I am testing Google Analytics Goals but I am not sure if I have it set up correctly. I set up a basic 3 step goal just as a test. I then went to my website and performed those three steps. Should that immediately show up in Google Analytics under the Goal reports or does it take a few days? I need to know so I can know if I need to be troubleshooting or not.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can see goals appear instantly in the Real Time Conversions report.

One other thing to bear in mind when testing: make sure you aren't filtering out your IP address as you won't see any results from testing.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Solve my problem. The standard reports may take a while and really hard to test viewing this page. But I can see the event right away from this Real-Time tab.

Answer (score 24):

It can take 24 - 48 hours to show up in the standard reports (Conversions -> Goals -> ...)

[Data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)

> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more
>   than 200,000 visits per day to Google Analytics will result in the
>   reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to
>   reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day
>   processing, reduce the number of visits you send to < 200,000 per day.
>   For Premium accounts, this limit is extended to 2 billion hits per
>   month.

Basic Goal Data can be found almost instantly in the Real-time -> Conversions report

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can take 24 - 48 hours to show up in the standard reports.But I could not wait to make sure if it is sending the right data so I used chrome extension. You can check the Analytics tracking code by using  [Chrome extension Google Analytics Debugger.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna/related?hl=en)