# Google analytics not show today data

Tags: google-analytics

I´m on homepage of Google Analytics, and when i click to show **today data**, its not load (and not show) today data.

I tried to delete the cache, im not using AdBlock and nothing else which could cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the free version of Google Analytics, you typically need to wait at least 24 hours before data will start populating in GA.  See this question: [How long does it take for Google Analytics Goals to start show some data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035909/how-long-does-it-take-for-google-analytics-goals-to-start-show-some-data)

Comment: Its typically show last 7 days data, but it has option to show last 28 days, yesterday and today. Yesterday its worked fine for me, but today not showing the today data (not load on homepage) - I have to go to Traffic and filter the todays date - then works fine.

Comment: Just as Brian has pointed out there is a delay in data collection and reporting in GA. Even if you get today's data it would be of partial day and the number will most likely be different when you pull the day's data (tomorrow's yesterday, which contains the full day). If you want real-time feedback, there is the real-time section in GA for you to look at activities on site at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it will show you the live data in reports(may be few mins delay)
Click on the Date Selecton on the top right corner of screen, then in "Date Range" select "today". It will show the latest data.

But the official time suggest by Google Analytics is 24 hours for free GA users and 4 hours for premium GA 360 users